# What was guru tradition of Sridhara Swami?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, resource

Are there any references of guru tradition of Sridhara Swami (commentator of Bhagavatam)? I did not find any information on him, his life etc., besides some blogs such as https://gaudiyascripture.blogspot.com/2019/10/srimad-bhagavatam-sridhar-swami-commentary.html

Comment: Sridhara Svami was a member of the Rudra Vaishnava sampradaya of Vishnusvami. See about that at https://btg.krishna.com/glories-sridhara-swami-quick-comment-crafty-commentator